# Copying data from one table to another while creating new row

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets; Tracker and Completed. On the Tracker worksheet there is table 1. On the Completed worksheet there is table 3. I am trying to use a button to transfer the highlighted row in table 1 to table 3 on worksheet Tracker. I am trying to have it where it creates a new row each time the data is transferred. I have tried a lot of different variations of code to try and make this work. This transfers all the rows in the table. I just need the single highlighted row to transfer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Sheets("Tracker").Range("Table1").Rows.Cut Sheets("Completed").Range("Table3")
```